# Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing

Tags: android, admob

I get a "Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing"  when I launch my app. This is written on the screen of my smartphone instead of my banner.

I tried the different solutions founded on stack (like `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"` or instead of `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`)  but it doesn't work.

Here's my java code (a simple Hello World just to try to implement a banner):

```
package com.example.publicite;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MyAdUnitId"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/votrescore"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.publicite"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.publicite.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 </manifest>
```

I use the google play service lib.

Comment: I think you don't need to redefine your ads namespace in your `AdView`. Try removing this line `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads` from `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView/>`

Comment: i get erros if i do this: no ressource identifier for loadoncreate and testdevices

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a weird answer. I just restarted my eclipse and it stared working. This might help some one.

Just restart eclipse, android studio or IntelliJ IDE

Comment: this is not an answer this is a prove that the error was the person between the keyboard and the chair

Answer (score 36):

Try changing your declaration this way:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

**---- EDIT ----**

You can also try to do it programmatically. Simply, instead of an `AdView` layout item, define a `LinearLayout` and by code do something like this:

```
final AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
adView.setAdUnitId("YourId");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

final LinearLayout adLinLay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.your_defined_linearlayout);
adLinLay.addView(adView);

final AdRequest.Builder adReq = new AdRequest.Builder();
final AdRequest adRequest = adReq.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: as I said, i've already tried this technic to just remove the 's' from the "libs" but even with xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" it doesn't work. I have the same problem :'(

Comment: But even removing the `s` you still see the `Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing` error?

Comment: Yes I was just thinking about it. I've also found this on internet:https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration?hl=en

Comment: It is written that the namespaces have changed .../res-auto it the right one and the attributes loadOnCreate don't exist anymore...Obviously I have to do an app when there is this migration. What a luck !

Comment: It's really helpful. i was try with this -> "xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" so i got this error and when i try with this -> "xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" then it is work fine.

Comment: Adding     ads:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID", and xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" works for me

Answer (score 9):

I have same problem.

Solution for me:

```
 xmlns:ads=""
```

changed to

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 8):

Problem fixed for me by changing name space uri

from

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

to

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: This was the solution for me, Thanks

Comment: That's actually the 'app' namespace uri. Thus you might as well just delete the `xmlns:ads=...` namespace alltogether and change the 'ads' prefix to 'app' in the corresponding lines.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I corrected it with the xmlns labels. I put two "xmlns:ads" labels (one for "res-auto" in the AdView and other for "tools" in the parent layout). I had to use two labels for "res auto", one with xmlns:app in the FloatingActionButton and other with xmlns:ads in the AdView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_start_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/fondo_proyectos"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/av_bottom_banner"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_inferior_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/av_bottom_banner"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/av_bottom_banner"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle" />

        <include layout="@layout/proyecto_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error. but I couldn't fix it with the pinned answer. I changed the xml to be like this.

```xml
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

The main changes are:
`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
and
`ads:adSize="BANNER"`.
I recorded my laptop screen while solving this issue. So If you like visual illustrations, you can see the [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/jw699yiX96g).

Answer (score 1):

change as below ..remove ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MyAdUnitId"/>
```

check this link, it has clear example

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

Comment: yes i did it. I remove this and the other attribute testdevice and now i have no more error. But i have no ad, just a button...I think the first atribute is important to add an ad

Comment: Yes  i just copy it from admob (monetizing section). But it's true, when i put something else like "3231165" for my ad id, i've got the same result: just a button and nothing inside. But I think the problem is because there's no more the attribute loadOnCreate, that is banned now due to their migration: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration?hl=en

Comment: hope you have done the code and manifest changes . adView.loadAd(adRequest); check the link I shared

Comment: Yes i'm trying to do it with a bit java now. Thanks

Comment: Link in answer is dead (Page not found | 404. That's an error.)

Answer (score 1):

This happen when eclipse failed to syncronize your xml with google play library, try cleaning project and restart eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Juste clean your app !

Build -> Clean Project

The message dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

That solved my problem, I hope it will solve yours.

Comment: Please remember to always include code as text and not image.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you **CANNOT** use `wrap_content` as a size, so you need to give it a size instead.
My ads weren't working and after a day of googling I changed my

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_height="100dp"`

and it fixed the issue.
P.S. `"match_parent"` does work (I have that set for my width)

Answer (score 0):

Check for DEIVCE_ID_EMULATOR too as in my code I have the following code from following the tutorial from Google:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .build();
```

In my case I was testing it on a real device so it never came up but just gave me the message that the adsize was not set.
I ran up an emulator and nkn's solution works perfectly.

Here is my complete code:
In main activity:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = newAdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

NOW run the app on your device and check out your logcat as it will show the line:
I/Ads: Use

```
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
to get test ads on this device.
```

Copy this id (DIFFERENT FOR YOUR DEVICE) to the .addTestDevice as follows:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = newAdRequest.Builder()
         .addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
         .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

AND That is how I fixed this issue in my case.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adMobBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"`enter code here`
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-39402560999425544/1033173712" // ID from google admob
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your XML file as below and do not set AdUnitID and adSize in Java file after setting it in XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the java code to

```
MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
 @Override
 public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

 }
});

AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          .build();
          mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, you are getting this error because you're not using ads namespace in your Banner's XML Code you should use like this.

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your minimum SDK version is 13 change it 16 by Google documentation
And maximum SDK version also 13 change it 28
It should be work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this.
Remember to add this line to root layout:

```
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

full code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```