# "adSize" was missing

Tags: android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to put ads in my app using Admob.

However, it keeps saying "Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing" even though that attribute is in my XML file.

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY UNIT ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Does any one know why this is happening?

Cheers.

Comment: Your layout has xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your layout has, `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` attribute, also why you have `layout_width` as `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content`, so try changing that too.

Look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#configure_gradle) if you havent already. Mainly there `activity_main.xml`

You entire XML layout file would help figuring out the problem too. You can remove the content you don't you want to post

OR, try changing your declaration to the following, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673265/4667831):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

**people have also suggested restarting your IDE**

Comment: It was the layout_width that was causing the problem. Thank you for your help.